# Understanding Mathematical Formula in Java

Tags: java, pi

Im just trying to get back into the way of programming in the Java language after having a rather large break so I decided to write a program that calculates PI to the users input number:

e.g. they enter 5, it would return 3.14159.

I've come across the Leibnez formula after a bit of searching but don't know how to implement in code. This seems to be a recurring problem so I'd like to rectify that. Anyone got any resources that demonstrate how to code mathematical formula?

For example, stuff that explains 1e6 and so on?

Cheers

Comment: Is there another language you're more familiar with implementing algorithms in?

Comment: *"stuff that explains 1e6 and so on"* - 1e6 = 1,000,000. Also, according to wikipedia: *"Leibniz's formula converges slowly. Calculating π to 10 correct decimal places using direct summation of the series requires about 5,000,000,000 terms"*

Comment: So you're saying the program would always return an output of 3.14... regardless of the input?

Comment: if you have questions like that then you should definitely do a tutorial

Comment: @kwikness input determines how many digits are shown

Comment: I think he's saying the input of '5' would mean to calculate pi to 5 significant digits after the decimal point

Comment: in this case, if the user enters 5, then it gets Pi to 5 dp. if they enter 20 it gets it to 20dp

Comment: @Douglas thats why im asking for resources. Any in mind

Comment: @Katana24 Sorry, I don't know any java tutorials off the top of my head. I'm sure there are tons of them on the web. Tutorials in general are a great way to learn to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point you could use this code, it implements the sum notation as described here [Leibniz formula for π](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80)

```
public class PI {
    public static void main( String[] args) {
        double PI4 = 1.0;
        for ( int i = 1 ; i <= 50 ; i++ ) {
            double nom = Math.pow( -1, i );
            double denom = 2 * i + 1;
            PI4 += nom / denom;
        }
        System.out.println( "result=" + PI4 * 4 );
    }

}
```

After 50 iterations the result is 3.1611986129870506

Comment: This only gets you as far as double precision will, which...isn't very far.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading a good math tutorial online so you understand the math first.  Then a good basic programming tutorial should do the job.

[Stack Exchange's Math section](https://math.stackexchange.com/) is a good reference of math concepts as well.